# Style and editors with authoryear-ext

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I have encountered several bibliographic style difficulties since using `authoryear-ext`.

My first problem is following the use of `innamebeforetitle-true` which allows the inversion of the editor and the title. Although practical, it changes the format by putting the first and last name when I would like "Author (I.) dir." I read in the documentation that the format used was that `in:editor (+ others)` but I don't know how to change it.

Second problem: I would like to put a dot at the end of the title (article title, proceedings, etc.). I can't do it for proceedings and inproceedings.

Third problem: I would like to put the collection and the collection number in parenthesis at the end. I got there but in the case of inproceedings the information appeared twice.

[image]

Thank you,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}     %permet de bidouiller plus en profondeur le code pour la bibliographie

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxbibnames=999,
maxcitenames=2,
maxsortnames=2,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,
giveninits,
mincrossrefs=1,
mergedate=false, %enleve le tiret
dashed=false,
introcite=plain,
autolang=langname,
innamebeforetitle=true, %inversion byeditor et titre
articlein=false, %enleve le in des articles
]{biblatex}

        %Etiquette, gras, avec deux points.
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}


%permet de mettre en minustile les styles de citation
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily} 

\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} %harmonise les étiquettes et les noms

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} %met une virgule à la place de tous les segments

%tri
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace} %enleve ponctuation entre prénom et nom.

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
    \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
        \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
        \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
            \ifcapital
            {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
            {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
            \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
        \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
        \ifboolexpe{%
            test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
            and
            test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
        {}
        {\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen}%
        \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
        \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
        \ifboolexpe{%
            test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
            and
            test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
        {}
        {\bibcloseparen}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
        \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
        \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
        \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
        \ifboolexpe{%
            test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
            and
            test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
        {}
        {\revsdnamepunct\bibopenparen}%
        \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
        \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
        \ifboolexpe{%
            test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
            and
            test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
        {}
        {\bibcloseparen}}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
        and
        test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
        \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
            \printorigdate
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \printlabeldateextra}}}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space\textendash\space} %limite entre nom et titre
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} %ponctuation pour dir. et prénom

%met en italique les titres
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}

%gere la commande in
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{inproceedings,incollection}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

%rajoute la date à la fin
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate%
    \newunit}

%rajoute une virgule à la place des deux points
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

%rajoute des virgule au lieu des deux points
\newbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{institution}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
}

%enleve les parenthèses pour les dates et les lieux de colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
    \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {\bibstring{presentedat}%
        \printfield{eventtitle}}%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
    }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
        \printfield{venue}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printeventdate}%
    \newunit
}

%permet de modifier citation
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    byeditor  = {\iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}
        {Établit\space par}%
        {dir\adddotspace\smartof}},
    in        = {\textit{in}},
    editor    = {dir\adddot},%
    editors   = {dir\adddot},%
    byeditor  = {dir\adddot},
    mathesis  = {Mém\adddotspace de master\addcomma},
    phdthesis = {Thèse de doct\adddot\space\addcomma},
}

%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea et enleve année supplémentaire
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseauthor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{author}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
            \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
            \ifnameundef{namea}
            {}
            {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
                \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
                \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
    \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

    %enlève la virugule avant dir. et permet d'enlever aussi la parenthèse et l'année supplémentaire
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{editor}%
            %   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
            \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
        %     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
        \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
        \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
            \printtext{}%
            \printfield{series}%
            \setunit*{\space}%
            \printfield{number}%
            \printtext{}}%
}} %%% il y a un point en enleveant \nopunct.

%permet de mettre collection à la fin en rajouter une virgule avant.
\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
    \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver #1.}}
    \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{series+number}
        \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}}


%permet de patcher pour les 
\patchseries{book}
\patchseries{collection}\patchseries{incollection}
\patchseries{proceedings}
\patchseries{inproceedings}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection,Proceedings,report]
{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddot\space}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{report}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
{\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%%% permet de mettre un point pour les booktitles
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
    \printunit{\adddot\space} %rajoute un point à la fin du titre du bouquin dans inprooceedings
}

%%%% permet de mettre un point pour les booktitles
%\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
%   \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
%   \printunit{\adddot\space} %rajoute un point à la fin du titre du bouquin dans inprooceedings
%}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @Inproceedings{Inproceedings2,
        author    = {de Vangelis, {\relax Cl}aire-Annie},
        title     = {Title},
        booktitle = {Book 2},
        year      = {2000},
        pages     = {320-335},
        crossref = {book2},
    }

    @Proceedings{book2,
    author    = {Hélène Henri},
    title     = {Book 2},
    year      = {2000},
    pagetotal     = {400},
    editor    = {Henri Point},
    address   = {Lieu},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    evendate  = {1990-10},
    series = {Serie},
    number = {1},
    venue     = {Actes du colloque},
}

    @Book{bookcollab,
        title     = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        year      = {1999},
        editor    = {Michel Jean},
        pagetotal = {680},
        address   = {Lieu},
        number    = {12},
        series    = {Serie},
        namea     = {Martin, Jean-Claude},
        nameatype = {collaborator},
        timestamp = {2019-06-15},
    }

    @Proceedings{proceedings1,
        title     = {Title},
        year      = {1990},
        editor    = {Michel René},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        address   = {Lieu},
        pagetotal = {294},
        series    = {Serie},
        Number = {1},
        venue     = {Actes de la table-ronde},
        eventdate = {1989-03-11},
    }
    @Phdthesis{these2013,
        author      = {Jean Martin},
        title       = {Title},
        school      = {Université},
        year        = {2013},
        address     = {Lieu},
        institution = {Institution},
        pagetotal   = {721},
    }
    @TechReport{rapport1990,
        author      = {Jean Claude},
        institution = {Institution},
        pagetotal   = {20},
        title       = {Title},
        year        = {1990},
        type        = {Rapport de fouille},
    }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: In future questions please only ask about one issue per question. The three sub-questions could have been easily separated into three separate question. Separate questions are easier to answer and are usually more relevant for other people. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `in:editor`. The bibmacro is called `in:editor` or `in:editor+others`. The name format is called `ineditor`, so you want

```
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}
```

instead of `\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{sortname}`.

---

For the period after the title you current patch approach works and can be extended for other entry types as well. `biblatex-ext` implements the `@in...` types slightly differently, so they have to be handled separately (they need to be patched twice anyway).

Remove

```
%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddot\space}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{report}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%permet de mettre un point à la fin du titre
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
{\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \newunit}
{\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
    \printunit{\adddotspace}}
{}
{}

%%% permet de mettre un point pour les booktitles
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
    \printunit{\adddot\space} %rajoute un point à la fin du titre du bouquin dans inprooceedings
}

%%%% permet de mettre un point pour les booktitles
%\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
%   \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
%   \printunit{\adddot\space} %rajoute un point à la fin du titre du bouquin dans inprooceedings
%}
```

and replace it with

```
\newcommand*{\patchtitleperiod}[2]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{#2}%
     \newunit}
    {\usebibmacro{#2}%
     \printunit{\addperiod\space}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to patch '@#1' driver for title period at '#2'}}}

\patchtitleperiod{article}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{book}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{inbook}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{collection}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{incollection}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{proceedings}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{inproceedings}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{booklet}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{dataset}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{manual}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{online}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{misc}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{patent}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{periodical}{title+issuetitle}
\patchtitleperiod{report}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{thesis}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{unpublished}{title}

\newcommand*{\patchintitleperiod}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibmacro{#1:parent}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \printunit{\addperiod\space}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to patch '@#1:parent' bibmacro for title period
        at 'maintitle+booktitle'}}}

\patchintitleperiod{inbook}
\patchintitleperiod{incollection}
\patchintitleperiod{inproceedings}
```

---

If you take a closer look at the `.log` file you will find

```
Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver incollection.
Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver inproceedings.
```

in the `.log` file. That is because as mentioned in the second point `biblatex-ext` sets up `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` slightly differently than the standard styles.

Replace the block

```
%permet de mettre collection à la fin en rajouter une virgule avant.
\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
    \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver #1.}}
    \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{series+number}
        \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}}


%permet de patcher pour les 
\patchseries{book}
\patchseries{collection}\patchseries{incollection}
\patchseries{proceedings}
\patchseries{inproceedings}
```

with

```
%permet de mettre collection à la fin en rajouter une virgule avant.
\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to remove series+number from '@#1' driver}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to add series+number to '@#1' driver}}}

%permet de patcher pour les
\patchseries{book}
\patchseries{collection}
\patchseries{proceedings}


\newcommand*\patchseriesin[1]{%
  \xpatchbibmacro{#1:parent}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to remove series+number from '#1:parent' bibmacro}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to add series+number to '#1:parent' bibmacro}}}

\patchseriesin{inbook}
\patchseriesin{incollection}
\patchseriesin{inproceedings}
```

---

In total (I noticed that your editor seems to completely mangle the indentation in the code blocks, which makes them very hard to read for me).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}     %permet de bidouiller plus en profondeur le code pour la bibliographie

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=ext-authoryear,
maxbibnames=999,
maxcitenames=2,
maxsortnames=2,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,
giveninits,
mincrossrefs=1,
mergedate=false, %enleve le tiret
dashed=false,
introcite=plain,
autolang=langname,
innamebeforetitle=true, %inversion byeditor et titre
articlein=false, %enleve le in des articles
]{biblatex}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} %met une virgule à la place de tous les segments

\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon\space}}


\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}


\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibnamedelimd\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#4}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct\bibopenparen}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd}\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\bibcloseparen}}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
  }
  {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
     {\finalandcomma}
     {}%
   \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
  {}}


\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} %ponctuation pour dir. et prénom

\DeclareFieldFormat{origdate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printorigdate
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space\textendash\space} %limite entre nom et titre


%met en italique les titres
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,unpublished]
{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}

\newcommand*{\aftertitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}

\newcommand*{\patchtitleperiod}[2]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{#2}%
     \newunit}
    {\usebibmacro{#2}%
     \printunit{\addperiod\space}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to patch '@#1' driver for title period at '#2'}}}

\patchtitleperiod{article}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{book}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{inbook}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{collection}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{incollection}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{proceedings}{maintitle+title}
\patchtitleperiod{inproceedings}{title}

\patchtitleperiod{booklet}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{dataset}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{manual}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{online}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{misc}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{patent}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{periodical}{title+issuetitle}
\patchtitleperiod{report}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{thesis}{title}
\patchtitleperiod{unpublished}{title}

\newcommand*{\patchintitleperiod}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibmacro{#1:parent}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \newunit}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
     \printunit{\addperiod\space}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to patch '@#1:parent' bibmacro for title period
        at 'maintitle+booktitle'}}}

\patchintitleperiod{inbook}
\patchintitleperiod{incollection}
\patchintitleperiod{inproceedings}


%gere la commande in
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\bibstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

%rajoute la date à la fin
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

%rajoute une virgule à la place des deux points
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

%rajoute des virgule au lieu des deux points
\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
}

%enleve les parenthèses pour les dates et les lieux de colloque
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {\bibstring{presentedat}%
     \printfield{eventtitle}}%
  \ifboolexpr{
        test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printfield{venue}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \printeventdate}%
  \newunit
}

%permet de modifier citation
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    byeditor  = {\iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}
        {Établit\space par}%
        {dir\adddotspace\smartof}},
    in        = {\textit{in}},
    editor    = {dir\adddot},%
    editors   = {dir\adddot},%
    byeditor  = {dir\adddot},
    mathesis  = {Mém\adddotspace de master\addcomma},
    phdthesis = {Thèse de doct\adddot\space\addcomma},
}

%% Pour avoir collaboration après l'auteur pour namea et enleve année supplémentaire
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseauthor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{author}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
            \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
            \ifnameundef{namea}
            {}
            {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
                \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
                \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \usebibmacro{bynameastrg}%
                \setunit{\addspace}%
                \printnames{namea}}}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\newbibmacro*{bynameastrg}{%
    \iffieldundef{nameatype}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{namea}{editor}}}
\makeatother

    %enlève la virugule avant dir. et permet d'enlever aussi la parenthèse et l'année supplémentaire
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
        {\bibnamedash}
        {\printnames{editor}%
            %   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
            \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
            \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
        %     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
        \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
        \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother

%met entre parenthèse la collection et le numéro dans la même parenthèse
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\space}%
       \printfield{number}}}}

%permet de mettre collection à la fin en rajouter une virgule avant.
\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to remove series+number from '@#1' driver}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to add series+number to '@#1' driver}}}

%permet de patcher pour les
\patchseries{book}
\patchseries{collection}
\patchseries{proceedings}


\newcommand*\patchseriesin[1]{%
  \xpatchbibmacro{#1:parent}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to remove series+number from '#1:parent' bibmacro}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{related}}
    {\usebibmacro{related}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}
    {}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{biblatex-ext}
       {Failed to add series+number to '#1:parent' bibmacro}}}

\patchseriesin{inbook}
\patchseriesin{incollection}
\patchseriesin{inproceedings}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,inproceedings,incollection,Proceedings,report]
{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}



\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Inproceedings{Inproceedings2,
  author    = {de Vangelis, {\relax Cl}aire-Annie},
  title     = {Title},
  booktitle = {Book 2},
  year      = {2000},
  pages     = {320-335},
  crossref  = {book2},
}

@Proceedings{book2,
  author    = {Hélène Henri},
  title     = {Book 2},
  year      = {2000},
  pagetotal = {400},
  editor    = {Henri Point},
  address   = {Lieu},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  evendate  = {1990-10},
  series    = {Serie},
  number    = {1},
  venue     = {Actes du colloque},
}

@Book{bookcollab,
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  year      = {1999},
  editor    = {Michel Jean},
  pagetotal = {680},
  address   = {Lieu},
  number    = {12},
  series    = {Serie},
  namea     = {Martin, Jean-Claude},
  nameatype = {collaborator},
  timestamp = {2019-06-15},
}

@Proceedings{proceedings1,
  title     = {Title},
  year      = {1990},
  editor    = {Michel René},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {Lieu},
  pagetotal = {294},
  series    = {Serie},
  Number    = {1},
  venue     = {Actes de la table-ronde},
  eventdate = {1989-03-11},
}
@Phdthesis{these2013,
  author      = {Jean Martin},
  title       = {Title},
  school      = {Université},
  year        = {2013},
  address     = {Lieu},
  institution = {Institution},
  pagetotal   = {721},
}
@TechReport{rapport1990,
  author      = {Jean Claude},
  institution = {Institution},
  pagetotal   = {20},
  title       = {Title},
  year        = {1990},
  type        = {Rapport de fouille},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Vangelis 2000 : Vangelis (C.-A. de) – Title. in : Point (H.) dir. – Book 2. Actes du colloque, Lieu, Publisher, 2000, p. 320-335, (Serie 1).]

Comment: Thank you.
I was sometimes on the right track but still very far from achieving what I wanted...
You are my hero