# abbreviated month name using biblatex.sty

Tags: biblatex

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,%style=numeric,
style=ext-numeric,%
citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{burdon_2011,
title={Pigs Float down the Dawson},
journal={Morning Bulletin},
author={Burdon, Daniel},
%year={2011},
%month={2}
date={2011-02-11}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{In}\intitlepunct}}}


%%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552249/biblatex-change-period-to-comma-after-year%%
\newcommand*{\aftertitlepunct}{\addperiod\space}
\newcommand*{\afterbooktitlepunct}{\aftertitlepunct}
\newcommand*{\aftermaintitlepunct}{\aftertitlepunct}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase:title]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase:title]{subtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printunit{\aftertitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{booktitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[booktitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase:booktitle]{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase:booktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{booktitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{booksubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printunit{\afterbooktitlepunct}}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}%


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

Please advise

Comment: You can set `dateabbrev=false` as `biblatex` package option.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, it's working fine, can you advise to meet the output as I mentioned, i.e., to remove the round brackets for `date` field, as I marked in the image, please...

Comment: That is a different question which is unrelated to the abbreviation issue, so better to ask a separate question about that (or try to find an existing question). From what I can find this is actually not very easy as it seems to involve redefining the date format (i.e., I didn't find a way to just use the existing date format but without parentheses).

Comment: Looking a bit further it is actually easy: `\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}` removes the parentheses.

Comment: @Marijn It's working like a champ, can you make these as `answer`, I'll accept it, please.

Comment: New Year wishes to you and your family too